# What is the component near air filter in Astra G

Tags: part-identification, opel, astra

In my Opel Astra G selection 1.4 I found a blue plug connection, what might be its use?

[image]

It's near the air filter.

Comment: It is to operate that component at the required times.

Answer (score 2):

It's a solenoid which is used to provide vacuum to a component. There are usually two things I've seen it used for:

1. Exhaust Gas Recirculation (EGR) valve activation
2. EVAP canister activation

I don't know which it's used for in your vehicle. You'd have to track the lines in both directions and see where it leads to.

Answer (score -1):

It's called a Canister Vapor Purge Valve

Comment: Hi Colin, welcome to the site. Could you elaborate a bit more on this, perhaps with some information about what it's for?